# Finding a string matching a given pattern and separating lines using Python's re module

Tags: python, regex

In a random string I need to find a string matching a given pattern, and put `;` after this string. I think I should use `re` to do it, but I am not that familiar with it.

Example input:

```
this is the first part of string 1/32 part this is the second part of string
```

as a result, I need to put `;` after the `1/32 part`, e.g

```
this is the first part of string 1/32 part; this is the second part of string
```

I know I should use `re`, and I know I should probably use `re.match` with a pattern looking like `[1-1000]/[1-1000]\spart` but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Edit: `1/32` is an example, it can be `65/123`, `1/3`, `6/7`

Comment: And why `[1-1000]`? What is your exact requirement? Does it matter if there is `/` or not?

Comment: Mind `[1-1000]` is a *character group* and thus will only match `0` and `1`...

Comment: You just need to match `\d+/\d+\s+part`

Comment: in line there will always be something like 1/32, 2/54, 111/355, ranging from 1-1000 on left side of / and 1-1000 on the right side. thats why i put these in bracket. And word part at the end

Comment: The way to say "a number from 1 to 1000" in regex is `[1-9]([0-9][0-9]?)?|1000`.  There is no support for arithmetic; you have to capture the strings which match the expression you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use case is called substitution. This is exactly what the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function is for.

```
import re

s = "bla 1/6 part bla bla 76/88 part 12345/12345 part bla"
print(s)
s = re.sub(r'(\b\d{1,4}/\d{1,4} part)', r'\1;', s)
print(s)
```

The output of this is

```
bla 1/6 part; bla bla 76/88 part; 12345/12345 part bla
```

Note the missing `;` after the last occurrence of `part`.

I used [`{}` quantifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to limit numerator and denominator of the fractions to 4 decimal digits, which is something that you mentioned by you `[1-1000]` notation. It could be even better approximated by `1?\d{1,3}` (but this is also not exact the same, it also allows for example `1999/1999`)<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
**p.s.** As [tripleee commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297928/finding-a-string-matching-a-given-pattern-and-separating-lines-with-re/42299071#comment71750915_42297928), the exact regular expression for decimal numbers ranging from 1 to 1000 is `[1-9]([0-9][0-9]?)?|1000`, it looks a bit complicated, but the building pattern becomes obvious if you separate the only 4-digit number `1000` and use a superfluous pair of parentheses on the 1- to 3-digit part: `[1-9]([0-9]([0-9])?)?`. Another option is to use the character class shortcut `\d` for `[0-9]`, resulting in `[1-9]\d{0,2}|1000`.

**Edit:**

- Combined the match grouping.
- Added the anchor before the numerator.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to use [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) from the `re` module, along with the below regex

```
import re

my_str = 'this is the first part of string 1/32 part this is the second part of string'
my_regex = r'(\d+/\d+\s+part)'

if re.match(my_regex, my_str):
    print(re.sub(my_regex, r'\1,', my_str))  # this will print: 1/32 part,
    # ...
```

Bare with the fact that you need to add some extra flags to the regex if you need multiple lines to match the same regex. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) a list of such flags.

You can see the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/nAmfmM/1)

---

A quick replacement (there might be better ways) would be to also match the parts before and after the desired matching part and do something like:

```
import re

my_str = 'this is the first part of string 1/32 part this is the second part of string'
my_regex = r'(.*)(\s+\d+/\d+\s+part)(.*)'

condition = re.match(my_regex, my_str)

if condition:
    part = re.sub(my_regex, r'\2,', my_str)

x = condition.group(1) + part + condition.group(3)
print(x)
```

Which will output the modified string:

> this is the first part of string 1/32 part, this is the second part of
>   string

A simple one-line function with all of the above would be:

```
import re


def modify_string(my_str, my_regex):
    return re.sub(my_regex, r'\1,', my_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(modify_string('first part of string 1/32 part second part of string', r'(\d+/\d+\s+part)'))
```

But I'd recommend keeping the condition. *Just in case*.

Comment: how to replace it in my_str, so it includes ',' after 'part' ?